# Where to add application tags in the Android Market?

Tags: android, tags, google-play

I noticed that some applications in the Android Market has field "Tags". But if I upload new application to the Android Market, no field with tag description is displayed.

Is it possible to add those tags into the application itself (define in `AndroidManifest.xml` etc)? Or tags can only be added to the description field in the Market?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think those tags are simply part of the description. They prefix them with "tags" to help justify why there's this random set of words at the end. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is all done on your Android market place when your setting up the description of your app.  Just leave blank lines above and below and place either keyword, or tags next to the list of words you have created.